# format and output all the data from a database table

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to make an page where all the things in the table in the database are displayed on the page. But in a nice format like something ebay where it shows the picture on the left and the title in the middle. Whereas I just have a list.

I can only seem to find tutorials which just echo out all the information which I don't think I can style around to make it look like what I want. I also tried using a variable to store it in, but I only get the last thing in my database showing up.

Here is some of my code:

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM BoatsForRent") or die("Error Searching");
$count = mysql_num_rows($query);
if ($count == 0) {
    $output = 'No results found';    
} else {
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($query))
    {                
        $id = $row['boatId'];
        $title = $row['title'];
        $type = $row['type'];    
        $address = $row['address'];
        $city = $row['city'];
        $postcode = $row['postcode'];
        $rooms = $row['rooms'];
        $decks = $row['decks'];
        $price = $row['price'];
        $title = $row['title'];

        echo "$title<br>";
    }
}
```

Comment: so what is your problem with this code, this will work good

Comment: What's the output and expected output?

Comment: Start with a mock up not using a database. Get that to look right first

Comment: my problem is that i want to be able to diplay the data differently not just as a list. @Kermani

Comment: MySQL is only going to give you the data ... to make it look nice you'll need to put the data into html and style it with css

Comment: Try to add the logic you wanted to do into your program. If you got any error, post the code you tried here with any error message return from webserver.

Comment: So i have to put this fairly large chunk multiple times and even then it will display all the results when i just want one at a time. @Mark M

Comment: Search for good web template and add your code to it! You are talking about a matter of design!

Comment: Get a good static page template that gives you the look you want. Loop through the repeating bit and fill in the appropriate values where needed. That's all I can say for now, this is too broad and you need to research.

Comment: @user3599634 There are some other options already posted, but see my answer for clarification on what I mean. The data is put into html tags, now you would need to add css to make the html look decent. Other have suggested finding a template, which might be a good idea, too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To style the output of the table, you can do some CSS like this:

```css
strong {background: #0ff; text-align: right; display: inline-block; width: 50px;}
span {display: inline-block;}
```

And you need to give your HTML as:

```
echo "<strong>Title</strong> <span>$title</span><br>";
```

#### Preview

[image]

#### Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/praveenscience/WBh52/

Answer (score 0):

Use divs, spans or tables to display your data in any way you wish to. Here is an e.g.

```
<table boder="0" cellspacing="5" cellpadding="5">
<tr>
   <td>Boat ID</td>
   <td>Title</td>
   <td>Type</td>
   <td>Address</td>
   <td>City</td>
   <td>Post Code</td>
   <td>Rooms</td>
   <td>Decks</td>
   <td>Price</td>
</tr>
<?php

                $id = $row['boatId'];
                $title = $row['title'];
                $type = $row['type'];   
                $address = $row['address'];
                $city = $row['city'];
                $postcode = $row['postcode'];
                $rooms = $row['rooms'];
                $decks = $row['decks'];
                $price = $row['price'];


    $count =mysql_num_rows($query);
        if($count == 0){
            $output = 'No results found';   
        } else {
            while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($query))
            {

?>

<tr>
   <td><?php echo $row['id']; ?></td>
   <td><?php echo $row['title']; ?></td>
   <td><?php echo $row['type']; ?></td>
   <td><?php echo $row['address']; ?></td>
   <td><?php echo $row['city']; ?></td>
   <td><?php echo $row['postcode']; ?></td>
   <td><?php echo $row['rooms']; ?></td>
   <td><?php echo $row['decks']; ?></td>
   <td><?php echo $row['price']; ?></td>
</tr>

<?php
   }
?>
</table>
```

Alternatively you can put complete table structure inside `echo ''`. You can now use css either external or inline as per you wish.

Comment: Thank you, that is a good idea , but i want to try to avoid tables.

Comment: then use divs or spans, just replace with span for e.g.
<span id="a"><?php echo $row['id']; ?></span>
and stylize it something like this 
<style>
#a {
float:left;
width:200px;
color: #F00;
background-color:#CCC;
display:block;
}
</style>

Answer (score 0):

You need to put the data into html tags. Here are just some very basic examples. Then you need to use CSS to add styles.

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM BoatsForRent") or die("Error Searching");
$count = mysql_num_rows($query);
if ($count == 0) {
    $output = 'No results found';    
} else {
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($query))
    {                
        $id = $row['boatId'];
        $title = $row['title'];
        $type = $row['type'];    
        $address = $row['address'];
        $city = $row['city'];
        $postcode = $row['postcode'];
        $rooms = $row['rooms'];
        $decks = $row['decks'];
        $price = $row['price'];
        $title = $row['title'];

        echo "<h1>{$title}</h1>";
        echo "<h2>{$type}</h2>";
        echo "<h3>{$address}, {$city} {$postcode}</h3>";
        echo "<p>This boat has {$rooms} rooms and {$decks} decks!</p>";
        echo "<p>The selling price is ${$price}</p>";

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The code you have regarded should be in your head section then the output of while should be changed to arrays:

```
...
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($query))
    {                
        $id[] = $row['boatId'];
        $title[] = $row['title'];
        $type[] = $row['type'];    
        $address[] = $row['address'];
        $city[] = $row['city'];
        $postcode[] = $row['postcode'];
        $rooms[] = $row['rooms'];
        $decks[] = $row['decks'];
        $price[] = $row['price'];
        $title[] = $row['title'];

    }
...
```

In the body section of your page choose good design for a grid or table and use `for` loop to populate the data:

```
<table>
<tr>
<td>ID</td>
<td>Title</td>
....
<?php for ($i =0; $i < count($id); $i++){ ?>
<tr>
<td><?php echo $id[$i];?></td>
<td><?php echo $title[$i];?></td>
....
<?php } ?>
</table>
```